# Count number of digits in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm currently counting number of digits using simple string.length approach:

```
val number = 829
val length = number.toString().length
```

I wonder whether this is a good way or there is a more appropriate way to do that in Kotlin.

Comment: Yes, it is except for negative numbers, they will have the minus sign counted in the length.

Comment: Some solution using 'log` would work too.

Comment: Since Kotlin 1.2, you can use `absoluteValue`. This covers negative numbers.  
`number.absoluteValue.toString().length`

Comment: The only wrong case is when the `number` is `Int.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: While the numeric solutions from answers below are better for performance, the original code in the question can be simplified to `"$number".length`, which, in my opinion, looks more conciese. I wouldn't advise to use this in a real code, though.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the standard Java-math library in `java.lang.Math` (edit: since Kotlin 1.2, use `kotlin.math`). The `log10` function will give you the length of the number minus 1 (with some exceptions). This function works with doubles though, so you have to convert back and forth.

A `length` function could be written like this in Kotlin:

```
fun Int.length() = when(this) {
    0 -> 1
    else -> log10(abs(toDouble())).toInt() + 1
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
println(829.length()) // Prints 3
println((-1234).length()) // Prints 4 (it disregards the minus sign)
```

Comment: I wonder why this wasn't included in standard lib. Btw, what is this condition checking for 'Int.MIN_VALUE -> 10' ?

Comment: Because `Math.abs(Int.MIN_VALUE)` overflows, I just hardcoded it in. `Int.MIN_VALUE` is equal to `-2147483648`, which is 10 digits long.

Comment: You can get rid of the `Int.MIN_VALUE` special case if you convert to double first and then compute the absolute value: `else -> Math.log10(Math.abs(toDouble())).toInt() + 1`

Comment: @fredoverflow Ah, nice. Edited.

Comment: And you can get rid of the `0 -> 1` special case by rounding the number up to the nearest odd number first: `fun Int.length() = Math.log10(Math.abs(or(1).toDouble())).toInt() + 1`, but this probably requires more lines of comment than lines of code saved...

Comment: Some comments about this solution that are differently done in my answer: 1. I wouldn't use `java.lang.Math` methods, but `kotlin.math` functions, then it is independent from the underlying runtime. 2. I would use an extension property, not an extension function. 3. The second example is wrong, it will print `-4` as you calculate `1234.length()` and then negate the result, you need to put the `-1234` in parentheses like `println((-1234).length())`.

Comment: @Vampire Thanks, fixed the problem. The `kotlin.math` functions didn't exist when I wrote this answer. It was introduced in Kotlin 1.2, which was released 6 months after I wrote this answer. For number 2, I think this is kind of stylistic. I prefer using a function in this case, because we are actually performing a calculation.

Answer (score 2):

This task could be solved recursively as following:

- check it the number fits in the range `-9..9`. If that's true, the result is 1.
- otherwise divide the number by 10, count digits in the result, and add 1 to that count.

```
fun numberOfDigits(n: Int): Int = 
    when (n) {
        in -9..9 -> 1
        else -> 1 + numberOfDigits(n / 10)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you don't want to resort to strings or doubles, you can use binary search on an array of integers:

```
private val limits = arrayOf(-1, 9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999, 999999, 9999999, 99999999, 999999999)

fun countDigits(x: Int): Int {
    assert(x >= 0)
    val result = limits.binarySearch(x)
    return result.xor(result.shr(31))   // one's complement absolute value
}
```

Of course, you could hard-code binary search for this specific use case if you wanted it to be really efficient, and/or you got paid by lines of code:

```
fun countDigits(x: Int): Int {
    assert(x >= 0)
    if (x <= 99999) {
        if (x <= 99) {
            if (x <= 9) {
                return 1
            } else {
                return 2
            }
        } else {
            if (x <= 999) {
                return 3
            } else {
                if (x <= 9999) {
                    return 4
                } else {
                    return 5
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (x <= 9999999) {
            if (x <= 999999) {
                return 6
            } else {
                return 7
            }
        } else {
            if (x <= 99999999) {
                return 8
            } else {
                if (x <= 999999999) {
                    return 9
                } else {
                    return 10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Either way, make sure you got all those boundary cases right:

```
class CountDigitsTest {
    @Test fun oneDigit() {
        assertEquals(1, countDigits(0))
        assertEquals(1, countDigits(9))
    }

    @Test fun twoDigits() {
        assertEquals(2, countDigits(10))
        assertEquals(2, countDigits(99))
    }

    @Test fun threeDigits() {
        assertEquals(3, countDigits(100))
        assertEquals(3, countDigits(999))
    }

    @Test fun fourDigits() {
        assertEquals(4, countDigits(1000))
        assertEquals(4, countDigits(9999))
    }

    @Test fun fiveDigits() {
        assertEquals(5, countDigits(10000))
        assertEquals(5, countDigits(99999))
    }

    @Test fun sixDigits() {
        assertEquals(6, countDigits(100000))
        assertEquals(6, countDigits(999999))
    }

    @Test fun sevenDigits() {
        assertEquals(7, countDigits(1000000))
        assertEquals(7, countDigits(9999999))
    }

    @Test fun eightDigits() {
        assertEquals(8, countDigits(10000000))
        assertEquals(8, countDigits(99999999))
    }

    @Test fun nineDigits() {
        assertEquals(9, countDigits(100000000))
        assertEquals(9, countDigits(999999999))
    }

    @Test fun tenDigits() {
        assertEquals(10, countDigits(1000000000))
        assertEquals(10, countDigits(Int.MAX_VALUE))
    }
}
```

All of this assumes that you don't care about negative integers. If you do, and you have trouble adapting the code, feel free to ask for help.

Comment: I'm sure others may find it useful, but for my purposes it's a little bit overkill. I was just searching for one liners. Nevertheless, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: For number of digits in a negative number, don't you simply needs to take the absolute value? Seems like a trivial thing to do... or am I missing something here?

Comment: @thecoshman `Math.abs(Int.MIN_VALUE)` is still negative... a classic :)

Comment: @fredoverflow that actually makes perfect sense. Think of 4-bit twos-compliment numbers. The smallest number would be -8 whilst 7 would be the largest (that's 1000 and 0111 in binary of course). The absolute value of -8 is 8; it's binary value *should* be `1000`, but we have twos-compliment, so it get's interpreted as itself. Yay computers!

Answer (score 1):

I would create an extension property using a base-10 logarithm.

If you want the `-` counted too for negative numbers it would be:

```
import kotlin.math.log10

val Int.length get() = when {
    this == 0 -> 1
    this < 0 -> log10(-toFloat()).toInt() + 2
    else -> log10(toFloat()).toInt() + 1
}
```

If you want to count only the digits counted and the `-` for negative numbers ignored it would be:

```
import kotlin.math.absoluteValue
import kotlin.math.log10

val Int.length get() = when(this) {
    0 -> 1
    else -> log10(toFloat().absoluteValue).toInt() + 1
}
```

You can then just do

```
println(1234.length)
println((-1234).length)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convet it to string type and use count function in kotlin, For example:

```
val c= "123".count { it.isDigit() }
println(c) // 3
```

If your value have the letters of the alphabet, it also works corectlly.

```
val c2= "a6li211".count { it.isDigit() }
println(c2) // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are not only digits.
For example: "-11.345F"

```
fun countDigits(str: String): Int = str.filter{ Character.isDigit(it) }.count()

// countDigits("-11.345F") == 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I compared this solution and this one seems a little faster (at least on my machine) than other answers.

```
fun Int.digitCount(): Int
{
    if (this == 0) return 1

    var count = 0

    var currentNumber = this

    while (currentNumber > 0)
    {
        currentNumber /= 10
        count++
    }

    return count
}
```